# How to convert varchar2 field into int in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field  **STATUS** with records 'Load Failed','Loaded','Partially Loaded'

I want to convert this **varchar2** filed into **int** field and case statement to implement the below logic

```
Loaded = 1,
Partially Loaded = 2,
Failed = 3
```

Can anyone please help me with the code
TIA

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the case statement to convert the varchar2 into int.
Add this to your query:-

Select case

when status = 'Loaded' then 1

when status = 'Partially Loaded' then 2

when status = 'Failed' then 3

else 'No status'

End

You can use functions like cast or convert for the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

select
case when status = 'Loaded' then 1
when status =  'Partially Loaded' then 2
when status = 'Failed' then 3
else null end as status_code